# Can Android RCS client can be developed with out SIM Card

Tags: android

I am creating a RCS client for the Android Device using the [Orange Lab Library](http://code.google.com/p/android-rcs-ims-stack/) But as per the code snippet the authentication is done on the basis of SIM card number. Is their any possibility to create RCS client for android with out SIM Card or Is it possible to create a fake/sim card for this purpose?

Looking for some help.